# Calculating Dimension of a family

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am interested in the following familly: all surfaces $X\subset \mathbb P^n$ such that $Sing(X)$ is a non-degenerate planer conic.

I was thinking about doing this: First this family projects onto the hilbert scheme of second degree curves in projective 3-space, so it is enough to calculate the dimension of the fiber.

So let $x^2+y^2=1, z=0$ be the eqations of a circle $C$. It is straightforward to see that $X=Z(f)$ has the property $C\subset Sing(X)$ if there is a decompostion:
$f=t_{d-2}z^2+t_{d-3}z(1-x^2-y^2)+t_{d-4}(1-x^2-y^2)^2$ Where the degree of the $t's$ is indicated by their subindex (so $deg(f)=d$).

I am having a problem calculating the dimension of the family of such $f$. In modern langauge i think that I am interesetd in  $h^0(\mathbb P^3,J^2_{C}(d))$, where $J_{C}$ is the ideal sheaf of $C$. So to calcualte it is enough to know $h^0(\mathcal O_{2C}(d))$ where "$2C$" is just $C$ but with the subscheme structure coming from $J^2$. I have no idea how to calculate this number.

Help please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the calculation you can use two exact sequences:
$$
0 \to J_C(d) \to O_{P^3}(d) \to O_C(d) \to 0, 
$$
$$
0 \to J_C^2(d) \to J_C(d) \to (J_C/J_C^2)(d) \to 0,
$$
and an isomorphism
$$
J_C/J_C^2 \cong N^\vee_{C/P^3} \cong O_C(-1) \oplus O_C(-2).
$$
Here $O_C(k)$ stands for the restriction of $O_{P^3}(d)$ to $C$ (so using an isomorphism $C \cong P^1$ this can be identified with $O_{P^1}(2k)$).

From the first sequence one computes
$$
H^0(P^3,J_C(d)) = (d+1)(d+2)(d+3)/6 - (2d + 1),
$$
and from the second
$$
H^0(P^3,J_C(d)) = (d+1)(d+2)(d+3)/6 - (2d + 1) - (2d - 1) - (2d - 3).
$$
Of course, this works only for $d \ge 2$.